# ItextSharp changing Userunit

Tags: c#, itext

If I change the userunit to 10 the size shown in acrobat is correct but when I import the pdf in CorelDrawX3 and X7 or in Rasterlink Pro5 the size get changed back to before Userunit was changed.

I have to change the userunit because the pdf is to big.

Here is my coding.

```
public void PDFUserUnit(string FileIn, string FileOut)            
    {
        using (var doc = new Document(new Rectangle(10000f, 16000f)))
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(FileOut, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.HIGH_PRECISION = true;
                    writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_6);
                    writer.Userunit = 10f;
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.NewPage();
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FileIn);
                    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
                    PdfTemplate tmp = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
                    canvas.AddTemplate(tmp, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);

                    doc.Close();

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I can't get past `new Document(new Rectangle(10000f, 16000f)`, you should be getting an exception from that since it is larger than 14400x14400

Comment: Googling around one find numerous articles explaining that CorelDraw versions ignore the recommendations in the PDF specification concerning maximum dimensions of page media boxes. So essentially one should not use those CorelDraw versions for PDFs with large page sizes.